# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Build Failed on XCode 6.4

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I have developed a sample application in IBM Mobile First 7.0 and added the iPhone environment.

I am trying to run the app using XCode version 6.4. But I am unable the build the app in XCode.

Refer the screenshot for the error.

[image]

I am able to remove this error by changing **other linker flag** in xcode from **debug** to **Obj-c**. If i do that, I can able to build the app, but the app is crashing on start up.

Any possible solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshots, there is 'duplicate symbol". So, you need to search for duplicate libCordova.a.

Another solution is to remove Derived data from ~Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: I am unable to find duplicate libcordova.a. Is there any way to find it? If I removed the DerivedData it is automatically rebuilding